# Firefox Throws SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE Error When Running an Angular Dev Server With --ssl

Tags: .net, angular, ssl, firefox

I am running an angular app using `ng serve --port 5001 --ssl --no-live-reload`

This worked for a few months but recently Firefox won't load the page. The error says:

> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:5001. Certificate key usage inadequate for attempted operation.
>
> Error code: SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE

This seems to be a Firefox specific issue. Chrome can connect without issue.

I think it's also worth noting that this project is usually a .NET project that runs an angular app and I can still connect with it when running via Visual Studio.

I have tried:

- Removing the "cert9.db" and "cert_override.txt" files from the profile directory.
- Enabling "ImportEnterpriseRoots" in about:config.
- Removing "/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem" from the project directory.

That same error from above is stilling being shown when I visit the page.

Comment: Update: I ran `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` and `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`. Then I ran the project again from Visual Studio which generated a new certificate. The issue is still happening and now Firefox shows the same error when running the project in Visual Studio as well.

Comment: Evidently the key usage bits and/or perhaps the extended key usage bits are not appropriate in the certificate. To see an example of what they should look like, just look at those fields in Stack Overflow's certificate for this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working. Here is what worked for me.

### The issue as I understand it:

When my certificate expired in late November of this year dotnet generated a new certificate for the project and started using that but it did not immediately delete the old certificate. Firefox then had two certificates with the same issuer and subject and since they both were self signed it didn't know which to pick and just threw an error.

### The solution:

I deleted the old certificate from Windows certmgr then I removed the certificate from Firefox Certificate Manager. **Important:** If you reopen the certificate manager before restarting Firefox the certificate comes back. You must delete the certificate from the certificate manager and then restart Firefox.

Firefox is aware of this issue and is taking steps to make the error message clearer at least: [Bug 1611381](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1611381)

I also found this bug about the certificate manager. Given how old it is I don't have high hopes that this will be changed anytime soon: [Bug 454782](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=454782)

I hope this helps.

Comment: This definitely helps and points out why it solved for me when I installed the beta version as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same issue. My React app was seeing this

> SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE

I attempted everything that you mention in the question, nothing helped. Then, I installed the Beta Release of Firefox [121.0b8](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/121.0beta/releasenotes/), it solved the issue for me. At this point not sure if they addressed the issue as I did not see any mention of that in release note, but this version solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It might be working in the beta because of the bug that I posted in my answer: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1611381. It seems slightly different though.